# How to remove the internal popup in IE and chrome

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome

There is a internal pop up in IE and chrome , i dono how this is coming , i can see this page even in google home page . please help me to remove this.

find the attached image.

[image: INTERNAL POPUP IN IE]

Comment: This is some additional software you have caught somewhere - it's definitely not a part of IE and Chrome themselves. Voting to move to Superuser

Comment: It looks like you have some sort of crazy spyware thing going.

Comment: any idea which sw its? and how to remove it ?

Answer (score 0):

- Look at add/remove programs for any unwanted software & remove it.
- If that doesn't work, Install a good anti spyware & remove it.
- If still problem persists run a registry cleaner.
- If still... format & install clean :)

Keep out from installing untrusted softwares in future.

Answer (score 0):

Well, asides from the [handy community wiki on malware removal](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware), i'd suggest trying to work out what process is causing this by using netstat -b to see what processes are communicating with that server, and killing the process/uninstalling whatever is doing it, and seeing if common antimalware will remove it.